Nx react testing with jest
Im trying to test an app project inside a nx repo that references components in a lib project. But it seems like it fails when loading the external lib, what am i missing. I can run the test just fine when running local testfiles in the @your-org/ui lib, since it don't reference other libs, but the app project fails.
I encounter this error:
Jest encountered an unexpected token

... (Jest failed to parse a file....)

Details:
({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){export * from './lib/accordion';
                                                                                  ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

  1 | import React from 'react';
  2 |
> 3 | import { Stack } from '@your-org/ui';


could it be some failed setup in a config file?
